# Loop through a range of an Array

Tags: swift

How can I loop through an `array` range? Example if I had 5 objects in an `array`. I want to loop from index [3] to end of the `array` in this example it would go through and update objects 3-5 and skip objects 1 & 2. This is what I have so far using the `stride` method(this code isn't working). Is this the correct method? How can I achieve this?

```
stride(from: markers[index], to: markers.endIndex, by: 1).forEach { i in
    // Do something for each array object
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the range operator to get sequences of indices or slices of the array. Which you use depends on what you are trying to do. For clarity I am going to leave out error checking.

For example:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
letters[3...].forEach { print($0) } // prints d e 

// or you can print up to index 3
letters[...3].forEach { print($0) } // prints a b c d

// or print elements 1-3 inclusive
letters[1...3].forEach { print($0) } // prints b c d 

// or print elements 1-3 excluding index 3
letters[1..<3].forEach { print($0) } // prints b c d
```

If you wanted to modify the elements of the array you pass in the indices rather than the elements

```
var mutableLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
(3..<mutableLetters.count).forEach {
    mutableLetters[$0] = mutableLetters[$0].uppercased()
}
```

notice here we need to specify both limits because the range knows nothing about the array.

It's often more *Swifty* not to modify things in place so, if this fits your use case you might consider something like this:

```
let immutableLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
let upperCasedFromThreeOn = immutableLetters[3...].map { $0.uppercased() }
// upperCasedFromThreeOn = ["D","E"]
```

As a final note, sometimes you need to know both the index and the element. You can use a `forEach` on the indices as above, but another way is to use `enumerated()` this creates a tuple of the index and element.

```
let range = 2...4
immutableLetters.enumerated()
    .filter { (index,_) in range.contains(index) }
    .forEach { (index, element) in
        print("\(index) \(element)")
    }
```

Here I've used a `filter` after the enumeration so that the indices match the original array.

Comment: This will crash as well if the array is empty or if it has less than 3 items. Note that enumerate returns the element offset (not necessarily the same as index depending on the collection type)

Comment: @LeoDabus it was explicit stated in the answer that error checked was omitted for clarity. Further more in the examples given the arrays cannot have different numbers of elements; *They're hard-coded.*

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate over your array slice dropping the first n elements:

```
let markers = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for marker in markers.dropFirst(2) {
    print(marker)   // this will print 'c d e'
}
```

If you need to change your array you can iterate over a slice of its indices:

```
let markers = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for index in markers.indices.dropFirst(2) {
    print(markers[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply *loop* through the `array` using **`Range Operator`** in *Swift* like,

```
var markers = ["M1","M2","M3","M4","M5"]
let count = markers.count
if count > 2 {
    for i in 2..<count {
        //add your code here..
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've used **`half-open range operator(..<)`**

Comment: This will crash if the array is empty or if it has less than 3 items and you try to subscript the array with that index